# Animate the position of an image based .on() .mouseenter()

Tags: jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/Pjp9x/6/
Problem:  I have a huge width image on a site.  Since it's a timeline I feel a great way to showcase it is a horizontal scroll.  I've created a viewport and two buttons inside of the viewport.

I'm trying to create a scroll of a imaged based where your mouse is.   Logically, I would like the image to add or subtract from left or right and animate as such.  Moreover, I would like the image to stop after leaving each entered space.

**JQUERY**

```
$(".move_right").on({
      mouseenter: function(){
        $('.image').animate({right:'-100px'},"fast");

      }
});

$(".move_left").on({
      mouseenter: function(){
        $('.image').animate({left:'-100px'},"fast");

      }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="move_left"></div>
     <div class="move_right"></div>
     <img class="image" src="http://img3.etsystatic.com/008/0/6026325/il_fullxfull.365768623_qlyl.jpg" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container{
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 overflow:hidden;
 position:relative;
}
.image{
  position:relative;   

}
.move_left{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    width:10%; 
    background:red;
    z-index:5;
    height:100%;
}
.move_right{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    width:10%;
    background:red;
    z-index:5;
    height:100%
}
```

My jquery skills are quite limited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're trying to reinvente the wheel, why don't you use this plugin: http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/#quickdemo